# Display two input values with '&' in-between them in another input box in onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html

I have three input box.If I type 'a' in first and 'b' in second,i should get 'a&b' in third input box. Help!!

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<input type="text" id="lname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<input type="text" id="gname" >
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var v = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var c = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    document.getElementById("gname").innerHTML = v.'&'.c;
}
</script>
```

**Update:** Also suggest me, I have to display only var v or r.But mine doesn't works.Please help

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="rname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
 <input type="text" id="lname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
 <input type="text" id="gname" >
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var v = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var r = document.getElementById("rname").value;
     var c = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        document.getElementById("gname").innerHTML = (v||r)+'&'+c;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: string concatenation in JS is with a plus sign. Thus, use `v + '&' + c;` instead

Comment: Please find the answer below and mark it as accepted if it has solved your problem.

Comment: You can use `String.concat` method also: `v.concat('&').concat(c)`. Or `Array.join`: `[v, c].join('&')`

Comment: Another issue: you tried to change `innerHTML`, but need to change input's value: `.value = '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Concatenation in Javascript is done using the `+` operator.**

See [this documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) and search for `concatenation`.

**Replace**

```
document.getElementById("gname").innerHTML = v.'&'.c;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("gname").innerHTML = v+'&'+c;
```

Also, **use** `.value` to set value of textbox instead of `.innerHTML`.

---

**EDIT:** Code updated with logical or operator as requested by OP.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var v = parseInt(document.getElementById("fname").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("lname").value);
  document.getElementById("gname").value = v||c;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="lname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="gname" >
```

Comment: @coder_tech IDs should be **unique** for each element in the HTML. Using duplicate IDs will render an **invalid** HTML in your browser.

Comment: @coder_tech You need to define a proper logic to selecting `v` or `r`, then the code can be written accordingly. EDIT: Do you mean to use the logical `or` ?

Comment: @coder_tech See the edit in the question above. Try to test it by entering `1` and `0` in the 2 textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Enter value<input type="text" id="textbox1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('textbox2').value = this.value" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" />
```